# How to add hyphen in class title of swagger.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using Asp .net core 3.1. I want to update the controller name in swagger.json of Swashbuckler.AspNetCore which is a auto generated file.
for Example  class title as School-Admin

I am using RestFul APIs, In Restful APIs, we use hyphen separated entities name
For example

```
Controller School-Admin
[GET] api/school-admins/1
```

As c# doest not allow hyphen in class name so I can't change my controller name..I want to achieve this usinh swagger..json

To achieve this I have added a hyphen in  [Route("api/school-admins")]
Right now, It works for Endpoints only and doest not add hyphen in class title. it shows the API and class name on swagger UI as:

```
SchoolAdmin => Class Title not hyphen separated on swagger UI yet
GET api/school-admins/{id} => API
```

My goal is to display class name hyphen separated on swagger UI  since swash buckle creates swagger.json automatically so it adds the class name same as mentioned in .cs file which is not hyphen separated due to language restrictions.
is it possible to change my class title in swagger.json without affecting auto generated functionality? I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore in which swagger.json generates automatically and also that file is non editable. Can I change the class name in this auto-generated swagger.json and push it into source control but it should not affect my auto-generated functionality of swagger.json.For example, if I add a new API or controller in the future swagger.json should be auto-updated with new changes only Dev need to add new class name hyphen separated if required.

Comment: There may be a standard Swashbuckle attribute to do what you want.  If not, you can write your own and process it with a filter.  I've done something like that (sorta-kinda) before, but it's beyond the scope of what I can do here.

Comment: `Can I change the class name in this auto-generated swagger.json and push it into source control but it should not affect my auto-generated functionality of swagger.json`. Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. `Swagger.json` must correspond to your API, because it's a sort of metadata for API

Comment: yes, swagger.json is the UI created by Swashbuckle to represent APIs. So Its represents the meta data of API.I want to change the class name in swagger.json  because I can't add hyphen in class name in c# so I want to achieve this using swagger documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting to help other
I solved it using APIExplorerSettings I was unaware of that before.
In startup.cs I use

```
SwaggerGen(){
options.DocInclusionPredicate((_, api) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.GroupName));
options.TagActionsBy(api => new[] { api.GroupName });}
```

in Classes

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "school-admin")]
```

and see the magic